# Porting C++ Application From XP to Vista/7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, porting

I have a C++ application that I have written for Windows XP, and I would like to port it for use on Windows Vista/7.  It uses some MFC (for serial I/O) and ATL (for WMI), but it primarily uses the good ol' fashioned Windows API.  What are some of the got-yas I should keep in mind when porting my application?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't need to do anything at all.  In general, applications written for XP run fine on Vista and Windows 7.  (Device drivers and other such low-level code may be a different story.)

Are you having problems running it on Vista or Windows 7? Have you even tried?

Some possible gotchas:

- security (does your app assume it is running as Administrator and has complete control over the machine?)
- cosmetic issues (due to changes in window and control appearance in Vista and 7)
- hard-coded file/directory paths
- a lot more users run 64-bit versions of Windows Vista and 7 than ever used 64-bit XP.  So if you have a 32-bit app and you dynamically load code (DLLs, ActiveX controls, etc.), you may run into 32-vs.-64-bit issues.

Comment: +1, Addtional note, for people wondering "Some app used to run on XP but not running on 7": Use [these detailed guidelines for compatibility with Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-compatibility.aspx). Also, if its someone's else app, use compatibility mode AND/OR **you can actually run Windows XP app in 7**, if you have [XP mode](http://microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) installed => It runs XP in virtual PC.You Install your app in XP. You find your **XP app in 7's start menu**! & next time run app (in XP style frame) without launching XP again!

Answer (score 6):

The Application Compatibility Toolkit will help you spot issues your application might have porting to Vista/Win 7:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2):

I'd second Michael Burr's suggestion to use the AppCompat toolkit, as that will spot most of the likely problems.  Some general rules of thumb:

- Don't write data to HKLM aside from in the installer.  Use HKCU.  Any read/writes to HKLM may be [virtualised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530198.aspx) and you may get very strange behaviour when switching between user accounts
- Don't use hardcoded paths, use [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Don't write data to system areas such as `c:\windows`, `c:\program files`, etc. If you do need to write data that has to be available to all users, use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` (`c:\ProgramData` by default)

Assuming that you do most of these things right anyway then I would think you won't have any major issues supporting Vista/Win7.